# Rebinding the arrow keys in VS2010 

Tags: visual-studio-2010, text-editor, shortcut, arrow-keys

Moving hands all the way down to the arrow keys can be boring... Is there a way to rebind the arrow keys to shortcuts, like in emacs ?

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use the external editor feature?

Comment: I'm intrigued by this question, as well as by the above comment. I'm bordering on repetitive stress injuries in my right shoulder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it !

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

The commands are Edit.LineUp, Edit.LineDown, Edit.CharLeft, Edit.CharRight.

Answer (score 0):

I think (tools)(options)(macro)(keyboard) will get you to the screen where you can assign stuff to keys.  (i don't have 2010 handy from here)