# How to rebind arrow keys for navigation in tools VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I have changed navigation of cursor in text editor as described in this question [Rebinding the arrow keys in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912974/rebinding-the-arrow-keys-in-vs2010/5939483#5939483)

I can't find same shortcuts for other windows. 
For example navigation up/down in solution explorer.

Does anyone know if it is possible to change these shortcuts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [article](http://lifehacker.com/5277383/use-caps-lock-for-hand+friendly-text-navigation) that features how to activate arrow keys(plus home and end keys) globally for all programs on the main keyboard via changing Caps Lock key behavior.